# Invoke a particular methods only once Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I have following architecture on my angular application.

Index Page-->Shell Page --> User view(From here User can we open subview)

every route change on my application goes through Shell page. On shell page, I have a function called activate which should be invoked only when the application is called very first time.

```
//This function primarily displays a toaster saying the application is loaded.

     function activate() {
                logger.success(config.appTitle + ' loaded!', null);
     }
```

Since routing chance goes through shell page, activate method is invoked even when it's moving from one view to the other view. I would like activate method to be invoked only very first time when the application is loaded not for route changes.

How do I get this working? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should move the logic for the activate method to a service. Angular services are singletons. So only one object is created which gets injected to wherever its required. This way you can persist some simple state over time. For simplicity lets say you have a generic utility service:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .service('UtilityService', UtilityService);

  function UtilityService() {
     var shouldActivate = true;

     this.activateComplete = function(){
        shouldActivate = false;
     }

     this.canActivate = function(){
       return shouldActivate;
     }
  }
})();
```

Then in the shell controller you would call that UtilityService and check if you canActivate, if so it'll run the activate function and then call the completeActivate function in the UtilityService. Now any subsequent checks to canActivate will return false:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('ShellController', ShellController);

  /** @ngInject */
  function ShellController(UtilityService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.activate = activate() {
      logger.success(config.appTitle + ' loaded!', null);
    }

    if(UtilityService.canActivate()){
       vm.activate();
       UtilityService.activateComplete();
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for. Thank you.